# Navigate to new page hosted on bokeh server from within bokeh app

Tags: python, python-3.4, bokeh

So I'm writing an application running on the bokeh server, and having difficulty with navigating between different pages being hosted. Let's say I have this simple class that loads a single button:

```
class navigateWithButton(HBox):

    extra_generated_classes = [["navigateWithButton", "navigateWithButton", "HBox"]]
    myButton= Instance(Button)
    inputs = Instance(VBoxForm)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        obj = cls()

        obj.myButton = Button(
            label="Go"
        )

        obj.inputs = VBoxForm(
            children=[
                obj.login_button
            ]
        )

        obj.children.append(obj.inputs)
        return obj



    def setup_events(self):
        super(navigateWithButton, self).setup_events()
        if not self.myButton:
            return
        self.myButton.on_click(self.navigate)

    def navigate(self, *args):
        ###################################################################
        ### want to redirect to 'http://localhost:5006/other_app' here! ###
        ###################################################################
```

and further down I have, as would be expected:

```
@bokeh_app.route("/navigate/")
@object_page("navigate")
def navigate_button_test():
    nav = navigateWithButton.create()
    return nav
```

Along with a route to an addtional app I've created from within the same script:

```
@bokeh_app.route("/other_app/")
@object_page("other_app")
def some_other_app():
    app = otherApp.create()
    return app
```

running this code I can (obviously) easily navigate between the two applications just by typing in the address, and they both work beautifully, but I cannot for the life of me find an example of programmatically navigating between the two pages. I'm certain the answer is simple and I must be overlooking something very obvious, but If someone could tell me precisely where I am being ridiculous or if I'm barking waaay up the wrong tree I'd be extremely appreciative!!

And please bear in mind: I'm certain there are better ways of doing this, but I'm tasked with finishing inherited code and I'd like to try and find a solution before having to rebuild from scratch

Comment: Hi, it appears you are trying to write a Bokeh app using the old Bokeh server from Bokeh 0.10 (or ealier). I have to discourage this, and enourage you to look at the new Bokeh Server starting with Bokeh 0.11 and later. The new server is faster, more robust, simpler to deploy, easier to write apps for, and vastly better documented. It's basically better in any conceivable metric, and is the only supported server going forward. Some useful refs: http://demo.bokehplots.com/ and http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: Well, I only just noticed the remark at the end. You would have to use a JS callback of some sort to call `window.open(url)` from JS, I believe. If you want this to happen on a button click, say, there is already a canned callback to open URLs: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#openurl